# Expressing "read-only, no modification of position" for std::ifstream

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, fstream, ifstream

In my code, I want to identify some properties about the contents of a file, before deciding how to read the file. (That is, I search for a keyword, if found, it's going to be read with `foo(std::ifstream&)`, else with `bar(std::ifstream&)`).

I implemented the method that searches for the keyword as

```
bool containsKeyword(std::ifstream& file, const char* keyword)
{
    for ( std::string line; std::getline(file, line); )
    {
        if ( line == keyword )
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This modifies the position of the file stream (either the end, if the keyword isn't found, or the position of the keyword). However I want that the position is reset after the search. This can be done with a ScopeGuard:

```
class FilePositionScopeGuard
{
   private:
      std::ifstream& file;
      using FilePosition = decltype(std::declval<std::ifstream>().tellg());
      FilePosition initial_position;
   public:
      FilePositionScopeGuard(std::ifstream& file_)
      :
         file(file_),
         initial_position(file.tellg())
      {
      }
      ~FilePositionScopeGuard()
      {
         file.clear();
         file.seekg(initial_position);
      }
};
```

Now we add this to the method:

```
bool containsKeyword(std::ifstream& file, const char* keyword)
{
    FilePositionScopeGuard guard(file);
    for ( std::string line; std::getline(file, line); )
    {
        ...
```

That's nice, because with exactly one additional line in the method, we get the behaviour of not modifying the `std::ifstream` no matter how the method is exited (one of the returns or an exception).

However, the method `bool containsKeyword(std::ifstream&, const char*);` **does not express the constness**. How can I adjust my method to express (at the level of the interface) that the method will not alter the current state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change the signature to take a position-guarded file:

```
bool containsKeyword(const FilePositionScopeGuard &, const char *);
```

This allows the caller to pass an `ifstream` per the current signature (constructing a temporary guard for that operation), or to make their own guard and use it for several operations.

You'll need to make the `ifstream` member publicly accessible.

Comment: Excellent answer! So simple and just as expressive as I have hoped for :)

Answer (score 0):

Do it with the text comment `// the method does read from file but resets the read pointer`.

Do not expect a user of the API to be a monkey at keyboard. Specifically don't mark `ifstream` argument as const while casting constancy out inside the method. It does make difference in a multithreaded program.

Comment: I'm the only monkey at the keyboard for this project (so far). I do use comments, but the are not as expressive as the keyword `const`.

Comment: if your API had static method or a free function `string peekLine(istream&)` it would have been *much* more expressive and clear than mixing it all together. Additional complexity should preferably be wrapped around, not mixed into or injected.